# AWS: Can Lambda permission policy have a source from target-group with wildcards?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I am currently trying to make most of the lambda integration with a load balancer setup in a cloudformation stack, and i am at the point of adding a permission to the lambda function to allow action `lambda:InvokeFunction` from a elbv2 target-group, so i thought on having the sourceArn in the permission to be like this:

```
arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-1:######:targetgroup/*/*
```

at this point i am just testing without adding the target-group resources in the stack, but after making the deployment in cloudformation and check the result of how the lambda function is composed, aws displays an error:

```
An error occurred while listing alb relations: 'arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-1:#######:targetgroup/*/*' is not a valid target group ARN (Service: AmazonElasticLoadBalancing; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID: 2ec4bd65-816b-11e9-b1a8-3d113de48409)
```

The policy result in lambda is composed like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "default",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "project-dev-FixturesDashgetAllLambdaPermission-17SATFJ9GT266",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "elasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:######:function:project-dev-fixtures-getAll",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-1:#######:targetgroup/*/*"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is done by a serverless framework, but the output stack resource looks like this:

```
{
  "FixturesDashgetAllLambdaPermission": {
    "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Permission",
    "Properties": {
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Principal": {
        "Fn::Join": [
          "",
          [
            "elasticloadbalancing.",
            {
              "Ref": "AWS::URLSuffix"
            }
          ]
        ]
      },
      "FunctionName": {
        "Fn::GetAtt": [
          "FixturesDashgetAllLambdaFunction",
          "Arn"
        ]
      },
      "SourceArn": {
        "Fn::Join": [
          "",
          [
            "arn:",
            {
              "Ref": "AWS::Partition"
            },
            ":elasticloadbalancing:",
            {
              "Ref": "AWS::Region"
            },
            ":",
            {
              "Ref": "AWS::AccountId"
            },
            ":targetgroup/*/*"
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Since lambda is showing error stating that the sourceArn is not valid, it makes me wonder if the sourceArn allows wildcards on a target-group resource, i've checked on a default `serverless` stack with defined functions do have generated permissions like this, i created my own permission based on that generated permission with sourceArn as the only difference.

Comment: Facing the same problem, anything that you can share to fix the problem ?

Comment: @Rajas Sorry, i did not post the alternative i had to come up with when i was working on this.. i will add an answer explaining what i did.

Comment: I see this warning in the AWS console too, but my lambda works none the less!

Comment: Incinerator’s comment deserves highlighting because it’s also my experience. The ‘error’ is annoying but my requests through the alb are returning status 200 from the Lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many tests, i have found out that `AWS permission policy` does not support targeting resource names with wildcards, since the work i had for this was being done on `serverless`, i ended up writing a plugin script to create a policy for each of the resources that were dinamically created in the templated.

Of course this ended up creating an additional resource for each lambda function created in the template, so it's important to keep in mind the amount of lambda functions that were created because this could rapidly reach to the resource limits in the template.

I could have worked on creating a sub-template for this purpose only, but at the moment i was working on this, it didn't seem necessary.

Comment: Thanks @Oscar for the detailed explaination.

Answer (score 1):

I workaround the circular dependency, and have all resources in one CloudFormation template, by:

1. create a default permission(without sourceArn, principal=elasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com)
2. create target group(dependsOn=1)
3. create a permission(sourceArn=targetGroup)
4. create a custom resource(lambda, dependsOn=2 & 3) removing the default permission from lambda's policy

Comment: I like this strategy, it certainly works. However, I don’t know how to remove the default permission using a cfn template - or even if it is possible. I need a fully automated solution.

Answer (score 0):

1) Create Stack with wild character "*" in AWS::Lambda::Permission
2) Once Stack creation is successful, a change to the AWS::Lambda::Permission needs to be made, i.e hard-code the TargetGroup ARN for AWS::Lambda::Permission obtained during the creation of the Stack. Only this code block needs changed (In the last line, full ARN of the target group needs to be specified that was created during initial stack creation).

```
HelloWorldFunctionInvokePermission:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunction1234.Arn
      Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
      Principal: elasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com
      SourceArn: 'arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:123456789:targetgroup/Example-TargetGroup/1234123213'
```

Stack Update: Below steps should be followed when there's an update that needs to be made to the Stack that would involve changing the Target Group.

Update the AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup logical name (if new Target Group needs to be created) in the template and remove the 'SourceArn' value and property within AWS::Lambda::Permission resource and update the stack. Add in the 'SourceArn' property back with the new ARN of the Target Group.

Comment: faced the same problem..all of this is happening because of this stupid circular dependency..waiting for a solid solution for this because I don't want to manually change anything after cloudformation ran.